# ArrayAdapter using ArrayList

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist, android-arrayadapter

I have problems with ArrayAdapter because I am using ArrayList of messages and I want to display messages data.

I have problem in getView because I am not sure how to go through ArrayList and show data correctly.

I did like this:

In **Activity** i have this:

```
        ArrayAdapterItem arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapterItem(DashboardActivity.this,
                R.layout.list_view_row_item, result);
        listViewItems.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

and in class **ArrayAdapterItem** I have:

```
public class ArrayAdapterItem extends ArrayAdapter<Message> {

ArrayList<Message> message = new ArrayList<Message>();  
Context mcontext;
int layout;
int messageNumber;


public ArrayAdapterItem(Context mcontext, int resource, ArrayList<Message> message) {
    super(mcontext, resource);
    this.message = message;
    this.mcontext = mcontext;
    this.layout = resource;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent ){

    ViewHolderItem viewHolder;


    if(convertView==null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mcontext).getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(layout, parent, false);

        viewHolder = new ViewHolderItem();
        viewHolder.textViewItem = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewItem); //ovde ih dodajem

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolderItem) convertView.getTag();
    }

    if(message!=null){

        while(messageNumber>0){
        messageNumber--;
        viewHolder.textViewItem.setText(message.get(messageNumber).getMessageText());
        Log.d("Lista AUTORA: ", message.get(messageNumber).getMessageText() + "");
        }
    }


    return convertView;


}

@Override
public int getCount() {

    messageNumber = message.size();
    return messageNumber;
}


static class ViewHolderItem {
    TextView textViewItem;
}
```

}

I have 3 message texts to display and it does BUT only first one have ok value, and other two has string from the TextView (It's not set). In log everything is fine, all 3 values of messages are ok.

Any ides what I did wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not completely clear on what your problem is.  If your `ArrayList` has three elements, and  you're trying to display a list with three entries, the above code won't do it.  `getView` is called once *for each list entry*.  The `position` parameter tells the method which list entry the method is supposed to fill.  You're not using `position` at all; instead, you're looping through the entire list, but that won't work.  Instead, try removing the `while` loop and using something like

```
viewHolder.textViewItem.setText(message.get(position).getMessageText());
//                                          ^^^^^^^^
```

Like I said, I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do, but I think you'll need to do something similar to this.

Comment: I just found problem! As you said I dont need while loop! When I JUST removed loop, it works!

Comment: @MalaAiko Yes, that makes sense, even if you don't use `position`, since you're using a `messageNumber` that will have a value equal to `something - position`, if the `getView` calls are done in order.  Please consider using `position`, though.  I don't think it's guaranteed that the `getView` calls will be in the same order every time.

Comment: Thank you for help, I will use position to be sure that everything is ok!